# Android-Universal-Image-Loader adjust view bounds not working

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm using [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and have some problem with the image size.

I set ImageLoaderConfiguration in my extended Application class:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024) // 50 Mb
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

and set DisplayImageOptions like:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_loading)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_loading_failed)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_loading_failed)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
        .build();
```

I create ImageView dynamically like:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutImage = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutImage.setMargins(0, 0, 8, 0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutImage);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

And I load the image from local sdcard. But the image loaded is cropped to like **1dp width** and parent height. The wrap content and adjustViewBounds is not working correctly as I expected.

Looking for any advice, thanks!

Comment: what is parent layout of ImageView ?

Comment: I put it in a Horizontal LinearLayout within a HorizontalScrollView. The height of the HorizontalScrollView is fixed.

Comment: Actually I just found that if I delete .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)) in the option, the image shows properly...